# How to prevent magnetic field from generating in current carrying conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Is there anyway  to prevent generating magnet field or nullify it.

Comment: mu metal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal

Comment: You can also use metals which behave like superconductors at certain temperatures, because superconductors have zero magnetic field inside their body.

Comment: Simply run an equal current in the opposite direction! :p. Or if you want to prevent a current from being created simply make an identical time changing magnetic field pointing in the opposite direction of the first field

Answer (score 1):

In your title you ask about preventing a current from a magnetic field.

One way to do this is to generate an equal but opposite magnetic field to the first magnetic field.

If the 2 fields are time dependent then they will cancel the currents generated

In the body of your question you seem to ask about nullifying a magnetic field generated by a current.

In this case simply run an equal current in the opposite direction of the first current.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering two conducting wires placed next to each other, magnetic field could be nullified by having currents in the wires flow in opposite direction. However the nullification will be only along a plane containing the two wires and between them.

Another situation is when two concentric cylindrical solenoids carrying opposite currents are considered. The magnetic field is nullified inside the inner solenoid. It is to be noted that the magnetic field magnitude, B=uNi has to be equal for both the solenoids.[image: concentric solenoids with opposite currents]